# Программный запуск testNG selenium тестов зависает

Tags: java, selenium, testng

При программном запуске selenium тестов с использовании testNG процесс виснет. Все тесты проходят успешно, но процесс не завершается и не возвращает никакой exit code.

Пример

Main.java

```
package com.example;

import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites = new ArrayList<>();

        XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();

        List<XmlTest> xmlTestList = new ArrayList<>();
        XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);

        List<XmlClass> xmlClassList = new ArrayList<>();
        xmlClassList.add(new XmlClass(TestOne.class));
        xmlTest.setXmlClasses(xmlClassList);
        xmlTestList.add(xmlTest);

        xmlSuite.setTests(xmlTestList);
        xmlSuites.add(xmlSuite);
        testNG.setXmlSuites(xmlSuites);
        testNG.run();
    }
}
```

TestOne.java

```
package com.example;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestOne {

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void prepare() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        this.webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        webDriver.get("http://google.com/");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void shutdown() {
        if (webDriver != null) {
            webDriver.close();
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 27439
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Apr 09, 2020 10:12:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Тесты проходят, но процесс не завершается

Дебаг и стрейс особо не помогли. Выяснил что зависает AsyncHttpTimer, который проверяет порт на localhost

Answer (score 0):

проблема была в альфа версии selenium

на github есть issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8159

переход на 3 стабильную версию решил проблему